# Paginate with find_each in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, will-paginate

I've got a huge set of records to display and have broken the query down using find_each:

```
 - Syslog.find_each(:batch_size => 2000) do |s|
   = s.something
```

The problem is trying to introduce pagination. I've tried will_paginate (3.0.3):

```
 - Syslog.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).find_each(:conditions => {  }, :batch_size => 2000 ) do |s|
```

Is there a way to paginate a large set of records like this?

Comment: that should work. are you getting any error message? are you using, will_patginate @collection, in your views?

Comment: = will_paginate(@collection) leaves me with error: undefined method `total_pages'

Comment: did u try saving the query into a variable like @syslogs, and using that in "will_paginate(@syslogs)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using will_paginate 3.0.3, I found the actual solution was to do this:

```
Model.accessible_by(current_ability).page(params[:page]).order('id DESC')
```

Found that on the will_paginate [wiki](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki).

Using that, I don't need find_each or batch size and have hundreds of thousands of records loading in a snap.

Thanks to @prem for his initial help. Plus one for assisting.

Answer (score 1):

Try to fire query using where on paginate as below

`Syslog.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page =>10).where(conditions: "your condition")`

That should work :)

Comment: Taken where out for time being. Using your method, same result - no errors, no pagination.. Very strange!

Comment: verify addition of will_paginate gm in your app and try taking the colelction into a variable and using that

Comment: Moving find_each into controller gives me an error: no block given (yield). That's why I moved to view for time being. WP gem working everywhere else

Comment: whatever the error its better to resolve in controller itself. its better to avoid querying in views. Try to move that into controller and query using where condition